# Computing cyclic decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ w.r.t. a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to compute the cyclic decomposition of a $3\times 3$ nontriangular matrix $A$, whose minimal polynomial is not equal to the characteristic polynomial, which guarantees that the space $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not $A$-cyclic. I computed it by some method, but I want to know whether my method is ad-hoc or is there any systematic way?

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 2\\2 & -1 & 2\\2 & 2 & -1\end{bmatrix} \hskip5mm \mbox{(operating from left on column space $\mathbb{R}^3$)}$$

**Step 1.** Compute characteristic polynomial of $A$ (it is $(x+3)^2(x-3)$).

**Step 2.** Compute minimal polynomial of $A$ (it is $(x+3)(x-3)$).

**Step 3.** Invariant factors for $A$ are $(x+3)$ and $(x+3)(x-3)$

(means, $\mathbb{R}^3$ has decomposition into subspaces $W_1\oplus W_2$ where $W_1,W_2$ are $A$-cyclic subspaces, with minimal polynomials $(x+3)$ and $(x+3)(x-3)$ respectively.)

**Step 4.** To get $A$-cyclic space for $x+3$, take any eigenvector for eigenvalue $-3$:
$$
(A+3I)\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}=0 \hskip5mm \Leftrightarrow \hskip5mm 
\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 2\\2 & 2 & 2\\2 & 2 & 2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}=0  \hskip5mm \Rightarrow \mbox{ we can take } \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Put
$$
W_1= 
\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle
$$
**Step 5.** To get $A$-cyclic space for $(x+3)(x-3)$, take a vector $v$ not in $W_1$; for example, we can take $v=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then,
$$
W_2=
\left\langle 
v, Av
\right\rangle =
\left\langle 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \hskip5mm 
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}
\right\rangle.
$$

**Step 6.** Final decomposition:
$$
\mathbb{R}^3= 
\left\langle \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle 
\oplus 
\left\langle 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \hskip5mm 
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 2 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}
\right\rangle
= \,\,\,\,\,
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ c\\ -c
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}
\,\,\,\,
\oplus \,\,\,\,
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}.
$$
**Question:** Is this way of obtaining decomposition systematic, or one can suggest other more systematic approach? (for shortning arguments, we can use symbols $e_1,e_2,e_3$ for standard vectors etc; but I am worrying about method.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an algorithm to find a cyclic decomposition of a matrix systematically. However, the justification of the algorithm is quite involved, so allow me to present you the algorithm, without justifying it first (i'll try to give you the ideas though).

This will work over arbitrary fields, so let $K$ be a field, and let $M\in M_n(K)$.

**Part I. Preliminaries on matrices with coefficients in $K[X]$.**

Let $S\in M_n(K[X])$. Let $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ its rows, and $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ its columns.

By elementary operations on rows, we will mean operations of the form $L_i\leftarrow L_i+Q L_j, Q\in K[X],i\neq j$, exchanging $L_i$ and $L_j$, or $L_i\leftarrow \lambda L_i, \lambda\in K^\times$ (and **NOT** $\lambda\in K[X]\setminus\{0\})$.

By elementary operations on columns, we will mean operations of the form $C_j\leftarrow C_j+Q C_i, Q\in K[X],i\neq j$, exchanging $C_i$ and $C_j$, or $C_i\leftarrow \lambda C_i, \lambda\in K^\times$ (and **NOT** $\lambda\in K[X]\setminus\{0\})$.

For $i\neq j$, we will denote by $T_{ij}(Q)$ the triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonale, $Q$ in position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere. We will denote by $S_{ij}$ the matrix with $1's$ in position $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ and $0$ elsewhere. If $\lambda\in K^\times$, we will denote by $D_i(\lambda)$ the diagonal matrix with $1's$ in position $(j,j),j\neq i$ and $\lambda$ in position $(i,i)$.

Matrices $T_{ij}(Q)$ will be called transvection matrices, matrices $S_{ij}$ will be called transposition matrices, matrices $D_i(\lambda)$ will be called dilatation matrices.

Note that these matrices are all invertible, viewed as matrices with coefficients in $K(X)$, and their inverses are matrices of $M_n(K[X])$. More precisely $T_{ij}(Q)^{-1}=T_{ij}(-Q),S_{ij}^{-1}=S_{ij},D_i(\lambda)^{-1}=D_i(\lambda^{-1})$.

The three row operations (resp. column operations) on $S$ described above correspond to left multiplication (resp. right multiplication) by $T_{ij}(\lambda),S_{ij},D_i(\lambda)$.

**Theorem**. There exist two matrices $U,V\in M_n(K[X])$ which are products of transvection, transposition and dilation matrices such that $USV=\begin{pmatrix}I_{n-r} &  & &\cr  & P_1  & & \cr & & \ddots & \cr & & & P_r\end{pmatrix}$, where $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ are **monic non constant** polynomials such that $P_1\mid P_2\cdots\mid P_r$.

**Proof.** This is equivalent to say that we may perform rows ad columns operations to transform $S$ into a diagonal matrix satisfying the conditions of the theorem.

The idea is to pick two non zero elements on the first row (say) of $S$ , and to perform Euclid algorithm to replace one of the elements by their gcd using the appropriate column operations. Doing that a certain number of times, we will get to the point where all the elements of the first row are multiple of the same element. We use again column operations to put this element in position $(1,1)$ and  make zeroes appear. Then do the same on column 1. We will get a matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\Delta & 0\cr & S'\end{pmatrix}$. If the coefficients of $S'$ are all multiple of $\Delta$ do the same on $S'$ and continue. Otherwise, choose a row  on which there is a coefficient which is not a multiple of $\Delta$, add it to row $1$, and start over again. The process will end at some point to lead to a diagonal matrix. Now rearrange columns to get the right order of the diagonal coefficients.

**Part II. Description of the algorithm.**

- Step 1. Compute two matrices $U,V\in M_n(K[X])$ which are products of transvection, transposition and dilation matrices such that $U(XI_n-M)V=\begin{pmatrix}I_{n-r} &  & &\cr  & P_1  & & \cr & & \ddots & \cr & & & P_r\end{pmatrix}$, where $P_1,\ldots,P_r$ are **monic non constant** polynomials such that $P_1\mid P_2\cdots\mid P_r$.
- Step 2.  Compute $U^{-1}$.
- Step 3. Let $X_1,\ldots, X_r$ the **last** $r$ columns of $U^{-1}$.

Write $X_j=\begin{pmatrix}R_{1j}\cr\vdots\cr R_{nj}\end{pmatrix}$.

Compute $v_j=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n R_{ij}(M)e_i$.

**Thm.** If $d_j=\deg(P_j)$,  set $V_j=Span(v_j,Mv_j,\ldots,M^{d_1-1}v_j)$. Then $K^n=V_1\oplus\cdots\oplus V_r$ will be a cyclic decomposition, and the matrix $P$ of the family $(v_1,\ldots,M^{d_1-1}, \ldots,v_r,Mv_r,\ldots,M^{d_r-1}v_r)$ into the canonical basis  will satisfy $P^{-1}MP=\begin{pmatrix}C_{P_1} & & \cr & \ddots & \cr & & C_{P_r}\end{pmatrix}$.

**Computational remarks.** We only need to keep track of row operations, so it's a good idea to perform as much as column operations as possible. Moreover, you can compute $U^{-1}$ step by step, and then perform steps 1) and 2) together.

Indeed , you have $U=U_mU_{m-1}\cdots U_1$, where $U_k$ is the matrix you used corresponding to the $k$-th row operation you did. Note that each $U_k$ is a transvection/transposition/dilatation matrix, so its inverse is known by the formulas above.

Then $U^{-1}=U_1^{-1}\cdots U_m^{-1}$. Thus, initializing $U^{-1}=I_n$ at the beginning of the algorithm, you can perform the computation step by step.

**Worked example.** Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}\phantom{-}1&\phantom{-}0&\phantom{-}0 \cr \phantom{-}0&\phantom{-}1&\phantom{-}0\cr -4&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}.$

We have
$XI_3-M=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}X-1&0&0\cr 0&X-1&0\cr 4&1&X+1\end{array}\right).$

We will compute $U^{-1}$ step by step, and we initialize by  $U^{-1}=I_3$.

Abusing notation, we will still denote by $U^{-1}$ the matrix found at each step. If $S_1,S_2\in M_n(K[X])$, we will denote by $S_1\sim S_2$
when $S_2$ is obtained from $S_1$ by elementary operations.

We have

$$XI_3-M\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&X-1&0\cr X-1&0&0\cr 1&4&X+1\end{array}\right)\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&4&X+1\cr X-1&0&0\cr 0&X-1&0\end{array}\right)$$
so
$$U^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\cr 0&1&0\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Then, we get
$$XI_3-M\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr X-1&4-4X&1-X^2\cr 0&X-1&0\end{array}\right)\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&4-4X&1-X^2\cr 0&X-1&0\end{array}\right)$$
and thus
$$U^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\cr 0&1&0\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr X-1&1&0\cr 0&0&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\cr X-1&1&0\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Next, we have
$$ XI_3-M\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&X-1&0\cr 0&4-4X&1-X^2\end{array}\right). $$
We then have
$$U^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\cr X-1&1&0\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&0&1\cr 0&1&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\cr X-1&0&1\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Therefore
$$ XI_3-M\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&X-1&0\cr 0&0&1-X^2\end{array}\right). $$
We then have
$$U^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&1&0\cr X-1&0&1\cr 1&0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&\phantom{-}0&0\cr 0&\phantom{-}1&0\cr 0&-4&1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&\phantom{-}1&0\cr X-1&-4&1\cr 1&\phantom{-}0&0\end{array}\right).$$
Finally
$$XI_3-M\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&X-1&0\cr 0&0&X^2-1\end{array}\right),$$
mutiplying the last column by $-1$, which does not change $U$.

All in all,
$$ U^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&\phantom{-}1&0\cr X-1&-4&1\cr 1&\phantom{-}0&0\end{array}\right). $$
Set
$$v_1=\left(\begin{array}{r}1\cr -4\cr 0\end{array}\right) \quad \mbox{ and  } \quad v_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\cr 1\cr 0\end{array}\right).$$ (the fact that there are no $X$ in $v_1,v_2$ is a pure coincidence. Normally, there are some $X's$ and you need to perform step 3) )

Let
$$v_3=f(v_2)=\left(\begin{array}{r}0\cr 1\cr -1\end{array}\right). $$
The theorem above shows that

$$f(v_1)=v_1,\quad f(v_2)=v_3 \quad \mbox{ and } \ \, f(v_3)=v_2,$$
a fact that you can check by hand
If $P$ is the base change matrix, we then get  $$P^{-1}MP=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\cr 0&0&1\cr 0&1&0\end{array}\right).$$

**Part III. Proof the algorithm.**

Later in the weekend.